# build a dom tree reading html using java

Tags: java

how can i build a dom tree by reading a html file using java. I actually cannot use anything except the scanner class. The dom tree structure should be build using linked lists where each node

Answer (score 0):

There are ready made libraries that do this for you. Try the jsoup library.

http://jsoup.org/

It parses the entire HTML DOM structure. It makes allowances for issues in the DOM structure and allows you to access the element text and attributes.

Comment: i cannot any external libraries. the only thing i can use is the scanner class